# If on certain page, use this LESS file?

Tags: less, pug

Working with Jade and LESS.

I have all my LESS files that import into a main.LESS file. One of the less files contains changes that I only want to occur while on the main page.

ex. .row normally has a padding of 50px, but for this one page I need it to 20px.

I have no idea how to go about this (I'm still really new to coding). It's part of an assignment, and all of the files MUST import into a main.less file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion; to take a look at [Changing selector order](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-changing-selector-order). With you main page having `<body class="main">` you can use:

```
.row {
  padding: 50px;
  .main & {
    padding: 20px;
  }
}
```

The above Less code compiles into CSS code as follows:

```
.row {
  padding: 50px;
}
.main .row {
  padding: 20px;
}
```